# How to create your own summary in R

Tags: r

I need to summarize the `TitanicSurvival` age dataset in R.

I need the table to look like this:

[image: summary of TitanicSurvival]

I tried to use the `summary` function like this:

```
summary(TitanicSurvival$age)
```

But I got this:

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 0.1667 21.0000 28.0000 29.8811 39.0000 80.0000     263
```

How can I perform the analysis as indicated in the image?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with the Tidyverse packages and the `gt` package to create the table:

```
library(carData)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

TitanicSurvival %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(`Sample Size` = n(),
            Mean = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE),
            `Standard Deviation` = sd(age, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-sex) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "sex") %>%
  set_names(c("Variable","Female passengers","Male passengers")) -> TitanicSummary

TitanicSummary
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Variable           `Female passengers` `Male passengers`
#  <chr>                            <dbl>             <dbl>
#1 Sample Size                      466               843  
#2 Mean                              28.7              30.6
#3 Standard Deviation                14.6              14.3

gt(TitanicSummary,rowname_col = "Variable") %>%
  fmt_number(columns = everything(),
             drop_trailing_zeros = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`datasummary` function in the `modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html) (self-promotion alert). This function uses the same formula syntax as the `tables` package, but it can save tables to HTML, Word, LaTeX, JPG, and more.

```r
library(carData)
library(modelsummary)
datasummary(
  N + Mean + SD ~ age * sex,
  data = TitanicSurvival
)
```

|  | female | male |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N | 466 | 843 |
| Mean | 28.69 | 30.59 |
| SD | 14.58 | 14.28 |